# MS SQL Insert from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I´m trying to insert values into a database from several tables:

```
insert dbo.Table1
(ID, IDTable2, IDCounter)
select
s.ID
o.IDTable2
o.IDCounter
from dbo.table3 as o, dbo.table2 as s
```

But the above code leads to the situation that i get duplicate values for the values from table 3, where i just want one value from table3 per value from table 2. (The tables don´t have any relationship info)

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Thanks everyone. I managed to solve it by adding a reference id to table2 and then using an inner join.

Comment: Well, what you do is a "full join" - you build the carthesian product of all entries in table3 with all entries in table2

Comment: That's called a *cross* join. A *full* join would rather be understood to be a full *outer* join.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That's what you get for spending second thoughts - I had first written "cross join"...

Comment: After going through it once more it may be better to restructure my tables to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: So for a inner join i need some relationship info in my tables correct?

Comment: @narain: Yes, to inner join tables they would have to be related somehow.That doesn't even have to be directly. Stores and Goods could be related by entries in an Assortment table. Crossword tables could be related by having the same length and letters in the same place. It all depends. Why not show us your tables and tell us what they are supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the clause for joining the tables table2 and table3, thus building a cartesian product. There must be something linking the tables; otherwise it makes no sense to combine them as you do.

My advice: Stay away from that old join syntax where you list the tables comma-separated. Use up-to-date join syntax (INNER JOIN ON etc.) instead.

Having said this, I don't see how your select will make sense anyhow. ID is to become the ID of table2 and IDTable2 is to become the ID of table2, too?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use full join as this will lead to table3 rows x table2 rows. Use inner join instead.